# Low-Poly 3D Models are exporting but materials aren't

Tags: animation, materials, uv, export, unity

I'm planning on making a short animation so I kept all the models, props and assets separated in folders. **Problem is, when I try to append each object into one scene, their colors (Basic colored Materials) is excluded.** I've also noticed the same problem when I open those files (FBX format) in Mixed Reality Viewer, and all I get is a plain object

[image]

compared to what I am expecting that was rendered in blender (see image below);

[image]

I'm EXTREMELY worried that I have to apply UV mapped textures to every model I made for this to work properly especially for the future since I need to be exporting these models as well in UNITY. **Any workaround on this or on how I may be able to fix this problem without applying uv map?** Note: I tried baking but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I've had the same problem. Apparently blender won't export color with a model because it is dependent on blender and won't carry over to unity or unreal engine. Must be done in the engine itself.